# matching html <form> with python regex except the "get" ones

Tags: python, html, regex, forms

```
outtext = re.sub(r"(?<!\")<form.*?>", "\g<0> <input > ", intext,re.I|re.M|re.X)
```

I have this regular expression in which I want to replace all `<form >` tags with  `<form ><input>` tags

Now the problem is i want to skip the substitution when the form is not a post means has a "method=GET", means I do not want it so match something like 
`<form method="get">`  but it should match `<form>` or `<form isform=1>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: not sure why it was not posted completely but i meant it should not match <form method="get"> but should match <form> or <form xyz>

Comment: I'd imagine Python has perfectly capable Xpath implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a negative lookahead to your current regex:

```
(?<!\")<form(?![^>]*method=\"get\").*?>
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jZ8oT9)